# SDL2 - Vsync not working

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I use vsync in my program, and it works fine until I minimize the window. I did this when I created the renderer:

```
renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
```

And here is the game loop:

```
while (running)
{
    checkEvent();
    handleKeyboard(timer.getDelta());

    render();
}
```

It gives me a stable 60 frames per second, but I get more than 100000 frames per second when I minimize the window. Why is that happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably just a bug in SDL. If you investigated the problem more: read docs do some tests, you can report the bug. It is likely going to be fixed pretty soon. Ryan and colleagues work great. :)

That being said. I would never assume that Vsync works on every system. You probably want to add in your own framerate limitation system. Relying on the hardware to limit the framerate is a bad idea.

---

**EDIT:**
I use this in my game to limit the framerate:

```
while (!gameLoop->done)
{
    int start = SDL_GetTicks();
    gameLoop->update();
    int time = SDL_GetTicks() - start;
    if (time < 0) continue; // if time is negative, the time probably overflew, so continue asap

    int sleepTime = gameLoop->millisecondsForFrame - time;
    if (sleepTime > 0)
    {
        SDL_Delay(sleepTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I limit the framerate by using SDL_Delay then?

Comment: How framerate limit is related to vsync? It doesn't even eliminate screen tearing, plus delay may be more than requested. While limit have its uses, it isn't truly an alternative to vsync.

Comment: When vsync is enabled, the framerate will be limited to the videomode refresh rate being selected. So this is variable. Vsync should fix tearing. When it is not in your case, then the videomode might be too quick for your screen. Note that not all videomodes would be 60Hz. So using it as a framerate limitation is a bad idea.

Comment: I put your code in my program and it makes clicking the quit button hard because you have to click inbetween a SDL_Delay call. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @BradyDean: That's very strange... I never experienced anything like that. You should just handle every event in the event queue. One of those events will be an SDL_QuitEvent. Take a look at event handling in SDL. https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent